# What does a BigQuery dry run return?

Tags: google-bigquery

The BigQuery docs say:

"Test your queries on smaller partitions of the table rather than one large table. If using the API, validate queries for syntax and get data processing statistics using the dryRun flag."

But they also say, for dryRun:

"If set, don't actually run the query. A valid query will return an empty response, while an invalid query will return the same error it would if it wasn't a dry run. The default value is false."

These seem to be contradictory, or am I missing something?

Comment: It will [populate the `totalBytesProcessed` field in the response](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query), defined as "The total number of bytes processed for this query. If this query was a dry run, this is the number of bytes that would be processed if the query were run."

Comment: Agreed Stuart - so the documentation for the flag is poor at best (I'd say its just plain wrong).

Comment: To clarify - "an empty response" vs "data processing statistics" is what seems contradictory.

Comment: Note that there's the extra complication that the query may return a not yet completed job, even if `dry_run` is set. See `Returns:` field for [this attribute from Python API docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.total_bytes_processed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see how these are a bit out of sync and could use some clarification.

Here's another description of `dryRun` that is more accurate. From https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs, search for dryRun:

> [Optional] If set, don't actually run this job. A valid query will
>   return a mostly empty response with some processing statistics, while
>   an invalid query will return the same error it would if it wasn't a
>   dry run. Behavior of non-query jobs is undefined.

It looks like the https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/launch-checklist documentation is just missing a bullet point between two independent suggestions.

I've logged an internal tracking bug for cleaning this up. Thanks for bringing this to our attention!

Answer (score 1):

No it's not contradictory.

The way I see it, the first message says "try to see if your query will be runnable by turning on the "dry run" flag".

While the second message says "If you have the DryRun flag set to true, it will return statistics about your query, so "totalBytesProcessed", without running your query, if the query is valid, and the same error that you would normally receive if the query is invalid"

So think of "dry run" as a syntax checker/error checking/checked for the bytes processed.

Comment: But it won't return nothing, it will return "data processing statistics", namely the number of bytes that would be processed. So the documentation for the flag itself is misleading at best.

Comment: Here @GrahamWheeler, I added Stuartd's part in my answer and switched it to "communityWiki", so I won't get anything in terms of rep, if you want to accept this one instead of yours ^^