# Is it possible to write tests for SQL in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Usually when writing code you can write tests, like Unit Tests in Java.
I'm not talking about syntax, the BigQuery Editor does a great job with that. I mean the semantics. Does the query actually fetch the data I'm looking for in the way I need it.

When analyzing data in BigQuery I don't really know what to expect, so all I can do is say "hmm, looks about right". But a lot of mistakes happen this way.
Often the SQL queries for analysis become very complex, so how do you make sure your SQL gives you the results you are actually looking for?
I'm by myself so I can't ask anybody else to look over it.

Is there a standard for this, if not, what techniques do others use to deal with the uncertainty?

Comment: have you checked the dry-run option? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334126/what-does-a-bigquery-dry-run-return)

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion based.  But for large queries, two compatible strategies come to mind:  (1) Test components of the query as you build it.  (2) Test on sample data that has a wide range of examples.  This actually isn't so different from testing other software on big data.